# How do I chain my normal and dynamic scopes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model, chaining

I'm trying to chain some scoping methods ([instead of using an actual scope](http://www.elabs.se/blog/24-scopes-are-obsolete)), but I have a problem combining them. I now have the code below working, but it's not completely DRY.
It would be way nicer if I could write something like

```
Project.from_advertisers(advertiser_ids).active
```

and

```
Project.from_advertisers(advertiser_ids).finished
```

instead of having to use the separate methods 'active_from_advertisers' and 'finished_from_advertisers' I created, as you can see in my code below. These separate methods work, but the preferred chained methods like above give me the error that the first is an array...

Is it possible to accomplish this some way inside the model?

Thanks for any help!

```
#### campaign.rb
# datetime   :start_on
# datetime   :end_on
# integer    :advertiser_id
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :advertiser

  def self.active
    self.select{|c| c.end_on >= Time.now && c.start_on <= Time.now }
  end

  def self.finished
    self.select{|c| c.end_on <= Time.now }
  end
end

#### project.rb
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :campaigns

  def self.active
    includes(:campaigns).joins(:campaigns).select{|p| p.end_on >= Time.now && p.start_on <= Time.now }
  end

  def self.finished
    includes(:campaigns).joins(:campaigns).select{|p| p.end_on && p.end_on <= Time.now }
  end

  def self.from_advertisers(advertiser_ids)
    includes(:campaigns).joins(:campaigns).select{|p| advertiser_ids.include?(p.advertiser_id)}
  end

  def self.active_from_advertisers(advertiser_ids)
    includes(:campaigns).select{|p| advertiser_ids.include?(p.advertiser_id) && p.end_on >= Time.now && p.start_on <= Time.now }
  end

  def self.finished_from_advertisers(advertiser_ids)
    includes(:campaigns).select{|p| advertiser_ids.include?(p.advertiser_id) && p.end_on && p.end_on <= Time.now }
  end

  def advertiser_id
    campaigns.first.try(:advertiser_id)
  end

  def start_on
    campaigns.map(&:start_on).min
  end

  def end_on
    campaigns.map(&:end_on).max
  end
end
```

Comment: @manu29.d answer is right, you should accept that.  `where` will return an ActiveRecord::Relation and you can apply additional scopes to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.select` will always return an array.

You might consider changing your queries using the `where` method.

```
def self.active
    where("end_on >= #{Time.now} && start_on <= #{Time.now}")
end
```

Comment: Nice! That did the trick.
Your code did not work for me, but when I changed it to where("end_on >= ? AND start_on <= ?", Time.now, Time.now) it worked like a charm!

Comment: No problem. Would you also happened to know how I can rewrite the other method ___select{|p| advertiser_ids.include?(p.advertiser_id)}___ to a where function without it becoming an WhereChain? Thanks!

Comment: It's `campaign.advertiser_id` right? your query would be `includes(:campaigns).where('campaigns.advertiser_id in(?)', advertiser_ids).references(:campaigns)`. This should work.

Comment: Please refer to this for more info [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Comment: Perfect! I found the reference, but couldn't make it work for me. You're a true hero!

Comment: be careful above code `where("end_on >= #{Time.now} && start_on <= #{Time.now}")`. That is opening your code to a possible sql injection. Better to have: `where("end_on >= ? && start_on <= ?", Time.now, Time.now)` Read here to see why: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Conditions

Comment: @ggrillone Injection?? How? There's no user input involved.

Comment: `.select` no longer returns arrays, if you supply a string expressions for the select to execute as SQL